# Building a custom UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uikit, uipickerview

I am trying to build a custom `UIPickerView` replacement class mainly for learning purposes but with a view to implementing this within an application I am developing. I have put a lot of time and effort into the UI of my application and now the default `UIPickerView` just doesn't fit right.

I saw this [Dribble](http://dribbble.com/shots/991626-What-time?list=users) mock up of a really slick looking date/time picker but realise that theres not a chance in hell that `UIPickerView` can be customised this heavily without some major hacking.

After a whole lot of reading and investigation, I have found that `UIPickerView` uses `UITableView`s for it's components rather than a plain `UIScrollView` as I had first assumed. This is confusing for two reasons:

Customising `UITableViewCell`s is a major pain in the derriere. It's not that it's hard work, just laborious and rarely yields the required result. Somehow `UIPickerView` manages to pull this off though with very little overhead. I would assume that each row in a component just uses `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` with a custom view for it's `contentView` but you know what they say about assumptions.

The second thing that is throwing me off is that `UIPickerView` conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, but not the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. This seems a little odd as the delegate is responsible for providing the correct height via `– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` `UIPickerView` however does allow you to set the size of a component via `– pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:`

In line with this, it also seems a strange choice to utilise a table view as natively these do not "snap" to a specified row the way a scroll view would with `pagingEnabled`.

Can anyone offer up an explanation of why the default `UIPickerView` doesn't conform to the aforementioned delegate? Would it be easier for me to implement my custom picker with a `UIScrollView` instead or should the `UITableView` provide the functionality required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `UIPickerView` actually conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` protocol but just does not expose that in public headers. You can check that yourself using `class_copyProtocolList` function.
2. Using UITableView internally makes it much easier to implement pickers with large amount of rows as UITableView provides great support for reusing cells, otherwise Apple would need to reimplement that logic once again for picker - that would not make much sense (sorry I don't see any big problems in customizing UITableViewCell for this case, so it is hard to comment on that)
3. As UITableView is UIScrollView subclass you can make it "snap" to a specific position, check `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method in `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol that can be used for exactly that purpose.

Comment: You raise a very good point here. I hadn't considered that the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol was privately implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Custom `UIPickerView` are done by mimicking it's behavior using an `UIViewController` subclass containing as many `UITableView` you need for fields.

Eg: if you want a time picker, use 2 tableviews

You should style them in a xib using images and such.

What's -kinda- hard about reproducing the behavior is the part where `UIPickerView` "snaps" to the closest cell, and especially getting it **right**.

Also, cells in a `UIPickerView` are simple, just no borders/delimiters between cells, text label is centered, and *voilà*. What you see are just images overlaid in front of the `UITableView`s.

As to why it doesn't *fully* conform to the `UITableViewDelegate`, it's because in fact, it's a lightweight `UITableView` that snaps automatically that is used internally in `UIPickerView`. Thus, it lacks some delegates that are not specially useful for this.

But I guess we all agree on one thing: **Indeed, building custom `UIPickerView` is a big pain and should be easier.**

Take a look at this component, looks quite nice, though I haven't tested it myself. [computerlogicx/AFPickerView](https://github.com/computerlogicx/AFPickerView)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I looked at AFPickerView previously but it's not quite as customisable as i'd hoped.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement an "alternative" `UIPicker` by extending `UICollectionView`.

Although `UICollectionView` is usually used for cases where you have multiple items in a section, you can just have one item and it works fine. If you enable paging you get similar behaviour to a `UIPicker`, but it has a "stickier" scroll that only lets you scroll one item at a time, which might be better if that is what you want. Furthermore, you can scroll vertically or horizontally. You could even have a 2D picker with some extra code.